# Missing task key: scalaInstance, while trying to run typesafe activator

Tags: playframework-2.4, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to run this command in a project:

```
activator gen-idea
```

I get this error:

```
Missing task key: scalaInstance
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix this?